# Bad Pointer error when using File* object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pointers, file-io

I just needed some advice regarding a bad pointer error I get using MS Visual Studio 2010.

```
FILE *rawDataFile = fopen("C:\\Data.txt", "rb");
```

While I am stepping through my code using both Release/Debug mode after the above lined is executed, I always end up getting a < Bad Ptr > declaration when I am watching the variable.

I really have no idea why this is happening, there seems to be no memory corruption happening prior, as far as I see memory is properly allocated.

I would really appreciate any pointers in helping me dig this further?

[image]

Comment: "I would really appreciate any pointers"  Well, you've already got four pointers:  `0x1035e4f8` (the value of `rawDataFile`) and three null pointers. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Bad Ptr>` doesn't necessarily indicate memory corruption, and it doesn't necessarily indicate an error.  In this case, it just means that the pointer is null, so the debugger is unable to provide any information about the pointed-to object (since the pointer is null, there is no such object).

The values of the data members of the `FILE` structure are implementation-defined.  In the Visual C++ implementation, these members are sometimes null.  This is normal.

Comment: You'd have thought that the developers of VS2010 could have special-cased nullptr...

Comment: @Neil:  What would you prefer to see?  The debugger is going to try to show the pointed-to value.  `<Bad Ptr>` indicates that it cannot do this because it cannot dereference the pointer.  Since the pointer is null, this is expected.

Comment: I would prefer to see `<Null Ptr>` or some such.

Comment: Thanks James. I need to dig further then, since I have a large existing program that I sectioned into a smaller project. In the larger project file I/O and some processing takes about 0.3 sec. The same short section (merely copy/pasted) in the newer VS project takes 1 second to execute. I though it was probably due to memory issues. But apparently not. When I watch the same variable in the previous project, I don't get any < Bad Pointer> status, it only appeared in my newer project. I appreciate the reply nonetheless ...

Comment: @Neil:  Well, it looks like the developers of the debugger agree that would be nice.  In Visual Studio 2012, the watch shows `0x00000000 <NULL>`.  :-) http://i.imgur.com/UMUmi.png

Comment: @c0d3rz:  You'll want to make sure that all of the compilation options are the same, especially optimization settings.  It would also be good to identify the part that is problematic by writing a small test program that only does that "problematic" work and compiling this test program using the same options with both compilers.

Comment: That is exactly what I've been doing James. No luck so far. I'm sure its something obvious ... I'll keep at it though.