# Visual Studio, reading file, get bad ptr

Tags: fopen

I, recently I use fopen_s:

```
errno_t err = fopen_s( &fp, filename, mode );
```

and I get errno_t as zero, which means no error occured, but I didn't get a valid fp, actually, it is unchanged.

What possible is this situation?

Comment: Please provide code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it encounter a NULL file pointer, which is not as expected, for why it encounter such a problem, please refer to this: [Bad Pointer error when using File* object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064475/bad-pointer-error-when-using-file-object)